# Scroll event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, scroll

I have this script: http://jsfiddle.net/jP3yw/6/

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll">
    <p class="scroll_item" id="1"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></p>
<p class="scroll_item" id="2"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></p>
<p class="scroll_item" id="3"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></p>
<p class="scroll_item" id="4"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></p>
</div>

<div id="first"> <h1>First div!</h1></div>

<div id="second"> <h1>Second div! </h1></div>

<div id="third"> <h1>Third div!</h1></div>

<div id="fourth"> <h1>Fourth div!</h1> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.scroll{
    position:fixed;
    height:48%;
    right:4px;
    top:30%
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.scroll_item{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
.scroll_item_active{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:3px solid #000;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#1').click(function () {
    scrollTo('#first');
}); 

$('#2').click(function () {
    scrollTo('#second');
}); 

$('#3').click(function () {
    scrollTo('#third');
}); 

$('#4').click(function () {
    scrollTo('#fourth');
}); 

 function scrollTo(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
        time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
        verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
        element = $(selector);
        offset = element.offset();
        offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, time);
    }
```

I want to change the class from scroll_item to scroll_item_active when you scroll to a specific div, even if you use the browser's scroll bar or the scroll menu. 
But I have no idea how to do this! Can someone please help me?

Live example: http://www.timotheecottier.fr/

Comment: You can inspire on http://www.timotheecottier.fr/js/parallax.js
function redrawDotNav()

Answer (score 0):

You should bind handler for [this](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event on element with scroll. And then when triggered you should iterate thought all elements you want to check whether they visible and use function provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling).